# При выборе на второй клавиатуре в телеграме (aiogram) сообщение не приходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

При выборе на второй клавиатуре в телеграме (aiogram) сообщение не приходит. те здесь:

```py
if message.text == "1" or message.text == "2" or message.text == "3" or message.text == "4":
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                                   text="""текст
текст 
текст
текст
текст""",
                                   
                                 reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

```py
kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb.add(KeyboardButton('вариант1')).insert(KeyboardButton('вариант2'))

kb2 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb2.add(KeyboardButton('1')).insert(KeyboardButton('2')).add(KeyboardButton('3')).add(KeyboardButton('4'))

async def on_startup(_):
    print('Бот запущен')

photo = types.InputFile('path_to_photo.jpg')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                         photo=photo,
                         caption="""текст
текст""",
                           reply_markup=kb)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send_golda(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'вариант1':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text="""текст
текст""",
                               reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text="текст",
                               reply_markup = kb2)
        if message.text == "1" or message.text == "2" or message.text == "3" or message.text == "4":
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                                   text="""текст
текст 
текст
текст
текст""",
                                   reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вам нужно что-то такое?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_golda(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'вариант1':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="текст", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="текст", reply_markup=kb2)
    elif message.text in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="текст", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```